# Javascript for loop nested iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to iterate through a large array of values and collect an average of one of the values for each second. I can't get this code to work properly, and as far as I can see the issue is with the nested while loop. am I making a scope error that's preventing me from iterating the for loop index?

The data is a timestamp in ms and a radiation count.
`a.data[i][0]` is the timestamp and `a.data[i][26]` is the count.

```
for (i = 0; i < a.data.length; i++){
    // counts is the count of radiation over the last timeframe
    var counts = 0;
    // t1 is the start time 
    // t2 is the current iteration time
    var t1, t2 = a.data[i][0];
    while ((t2 - t1) < 1000){
        t2 = a.data[i][0];
        counts += a.data[i][26];
        i++;
    }
    // Geiger Data is an array of { x:(time), y:(value)} datapoints.
    GeigerData.push({x: (t1/1000), y: counts});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem stems from this line:

```
 var t1, t2 = a.data[i][0];
```

Defining JS variables doesn't work like that, and in your code `t1` is always undefined.  What you really want is

```
 var t1 = a.data[i][0];
 var t2 = t1;
```

Comment: This could also be done `var t1 = t2 = a.data[i][0]`

Comment: @JonathanCrowe - technically, yes, you could do that, but you super don't want to.  Your code is the same as doing this: 

    `var t1 = a.data[i][0]; `
    `t2 = t1;`

This puts t2 in the global scope, by not using var.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucyewprL/